# How to download the file using javascript xpath in pyhton

Tags: selenium-webdriver

It is a pop up window coming and I wish to download the file using python selenium webdriver(chrome driver). However it is not taking the switch to alert text. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide source HTML that is being used in the example?

Comment: Yes.

It is as:

<button onclick="javascript:downloadFile('/MemberPassBook/passbook//downloads/download-file?token=TA22Yo_i12voqeTPQ0gpQykoPjrpSKrkXXijeIzjUh35qY1CH2dm7tdBRRiFMybnG2cwFHGG4Dos6NUX_1Iwp_1oTMN_cb8mHuDm5IiZxLGc9rrpSgx0yBWGZ2qoQJdf&amp;mid=GNGGN00252040000502992')" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right">Download File <i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>

Comment: I got the error :

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e8534a74cd94> in <module>
----> 1 driver.find_element(By.xpath("//div[. = 'btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right']")).click();

NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong and you are clicking a wrong tag, and also you have to import By class

You should click-Button element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are locating a `div` element but you want to click on a `button`. Generally `div` is a container and many time it not receive clicks.

> Another thing and best practice is to use webdriver wait if element is
>   clickable then wait for element to receive click if element is not
>   clickable then atleast wait for visibility of element.

Please try below code using `CSS` with `webdriver explicit wait`.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-sm.btn-success.pull-right")))
element.click()
```

**you need below import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```